# Eclipse for android on Debian Lenny

Tags: android, eclipse, debian

I have installed Eclipse on Debian Lenny after having installed java (apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-jdk).

When I run Eclipse, I have the following message when it comes to selet the folder that will be used as the workspace:

```
GCJ has been detected as the current Java virtual machine.
Use of GCJ is untested and unsupported.
Please consult the documentation for more
```

I just ignored this message and go into "help" -> "software updates" to install android development tools. When I add "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" to download the Developer tools, I got an error (see below) and the installation cannot go any further.
Is that due to the Garbage Collector message I got above ?

Below are the error I got on the console from which I run eclipse:

```
lj:/home/luc# eclipse/eclipse
GC Warning: Out of Memory!  Returning NIL!
GC Warning: Out of Memory!  Returning NIL!
GC Warning: Out of Memory!  Returning NIL!
GC Warning: Out of Memory!  Returning NIL!
GC Warning: Out of Memory!  Returning NIL!
Error while logging event loop exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
<<No stacktrace available>>
Logging exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
<<No stacktrace available>>
GC Warning: Out of Memory!  Returning NIL!
....
```

Thanks a lot for your help,
Luc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is your clue:

```
GCJ has been detected as the current Java virtual machine.
```

That means your system Java is still the GCJ version, not the Sun version.

If you don't need GCJ for other things, you can remove the package (`apt-get remove` or `apt-get purge`).  This might break other dependencies though.

Otherwise, use `update-alternatives` to configure which package supplies your `java` and `javac` commands:

```
update-alternatives --config java
update-alternatives --config javac
```

[Source](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/debian/java.jspx)